# SQL Server Compact. There was an error parsing the query

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I cannot figure out why this is not working.  I get the same thing when I try to do an update query as well.

Here is the error " There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 43,Token in error = where ] "

Here is the actual Query `INSERT INTO ads (title,price,body,enabled,where,interval,posted) VALUES('test','899','test',True,'Columbus',15,'11/25/2009 10:12:30 AM')`

Where would be 'Columbus'

I am using visual studio express 2008 C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WHERE is a reserved word, try wrapping it in brackets

```
INSERT INTO ads (title,price,body,enabled,[where],interval,posted) 
VALUES('test','899','test',True,'Columbus',15,'11/25/2009 10:12:30 AM')
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was it but putting brackets didn't help, I had to change the name of the column entirely.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should provide the value of the primary key in your insert statement,maybe SQL Server Compact databases are not generated automatically or you dont configure that.

I had the same problem this is the INSERT statement which was not working and got the same error:

```
INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerName,CustomerAddress,CustomerPhone)
 VALUES ('Osama','Amman','656565')
```

this is the INSERT statement which was working fine:

```
INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerAddress,CustomerPhone)
 VALUES ('4564','Osama','Amman','656565')
```

also if you have in your table columns with names have spaces like (Customer Name)
you must use brackets in your sqlCe statement as:

```
INSERT INTO Customers([CustomerID],[Customer Name],[Customer Address],[Customer Phone])
 VALUES ('4564','Osama','Amman','656565')
```

also if you use  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get last record inserted in INSERT Statement
as:

```
INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerAddress,CustomerPhone)
 VALUES ('4564','Osama','Amman','656565')  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

don't use it...